# Rewrite Long URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

If I have an URL like this :

```
http://www.example.com/book.php?translate=id&surah=1&verse=1&and=4&audio=on&hl=yes
```

and I want to reqrite to new URL like this :

```
http://www.example.com/quran/id/1/1/4/on/hl/
```

how to do this in htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by the `hl` you meant `yes` this is what  you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^quran/?([A-Za-z0-9]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9]+)?/?$    book.php?translate=$1&surah=$2&verse=$3&and=$4&audio=$5&hl=$6    [NC,L]
```

Comment: the result is still same @newpeople

Comment: @Ferdian I made it less obligatory. see the edit and let me if it works. btw I tested it myslef and it should work now!

Comment: you can see the Real URL below :

http://www.mushaf.id/quran/1/1/4/id/on

the Real URL is :

http://www.mushaf.id/book.php?surah=1&verse=1&and=4&translate=id&audio=on

Comment: @Ferdian Im glad its working! btw your website contains sql problems. take care of it if security is a concern.

Comment: Yes, just a small edit for css and the other files. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ferdian If you dont see the css files loading thats because you addressed them relatively. like `mine.css` you addressed it `sources/css/mine.css` put a slash before it `/sources/css/mine.css` in page's html to make it get those files absolutely from the base path.

Comment: great, thanks a lot @newpeople 
you're the best one :)

Comment: One more, how if the url skip some part?

ie: `quran/id/1/2/4/on/yes`
and I want the url also work for `quran/id/1/2/on/` or `quran/id/1/on`

Comment: @Ferdian Those arguments are sequential, and in my last edit I made it not-obligatory meaning that if you for example open `quran/id/1/2/4` it will work but the two last parameters get empty value in the php file getting those. Because those are sequential they should come after one another and for eg if you put `yes` before `on` it does not spawn any errors but the variables in php file get the wrong value for that last two params. For what you want there _is_ a way but I encourage you ask a new question and link it here and I will answer it asap :)

Answer (score 0):

TO use it in php you can modify put in the htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

And in the index.php

```
<?php
  #In here you remove the path you don't want
  $request  = str_replace("/envato/pretty/php/", "", 
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  #get the params by splitting
  $params = split("/", $request);
?>
```

Comment: can you give me the detailed of your script and how to aplicate to my URL ?
I'm new to htaccess :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you use which version,but You can get that in documents

then you need set "URL_MODE"

Comment: I'm using php, and apache server

Comment: tp?set URL_MODE=>2  and open rewrite in apache server,it can solve your questions